# Manually include assets in SailsJS 0.9.7

Tags: javascript, sails.js, assets

I'm trying to manually include some assets in SailsJS, however I can't get them to work. They keep 404'ing.

The config/routes.js comments tell me that and image in assets/images/1.png would be accessible via `href="images/1.png"`. The same thing doesn't seem to apply for stylesheets as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">` results in a 404 not found.

I saw that Sails uses a very extensive Gruntfile as of lately, but I wanted a bit more control so I ditched it. I know that breaks the automatic including of assets, but did that also break the manually insertion? :(

**Edit:**
I found in the documentation that public assets aren't served from the assets folder anymore, but from the .tmp/public folder. Is there a way I can change this behaviour and just use the assets/ folder as a public facing directory?

Another option would of course be to simply use Sails' Gruntfile approach, but it keeps throwing less compiler errors even though when I compile things manually using `lessc` everything works fine...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you delete the `Gruntfile.js`, none of your assets will be managed by sails.

### Where do I put my css and javascript assets in sails?

Sails uses [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to manage assets.  Some of this "management" involves syncing files between your project folder structure and the server's public folder, but as always, I'm getting ahead of myself.

The configuration of `grunt` is based upon the `Gruntfile.js` file found in the root of your sails project.  There’s a lot going on in this file, however, I’m going to concentrate on the javascript and css assets.

#### Your Project's Assets

When you first create a project, you have the option of using the `--linker` flag.  An example of using the flag would be `sails new projectName --linker`. Here’s the directory structure of the `/assets` folder under both scenarios:

**USING** the `--linker` flag

```
/assets
 /images
 /linker
  /js
  /styles
  /templates
```

**NOT USING** the `--linker` flag

```
/assets
 /images
 /js
 /styles
```

Note, you can “upgrade” a project that wasn't created with the `--linker` flag by manually creating the `/linker` folder and inserting it into your `/assets` path.  You can then add `/js`, `/styles`, and `/templates` under `/linker`.

#### The Server's Public Folder

When starting the sails server via `sails lift` the following folder structure is created/sync'd via `grunt` within the `.tmp` folder:

```
.tmp
  /public
```

If any of the other project folders (e.g. `/images`, `/js`, `/styles`, `/templates`) contain content they are copied/sync'd to the `.tmp/public`folder.  The distinction being that if a `/linker` folder exists, the `/js`, `/styles`, and an additional `/templates` folder is created under `/linker`.

#### What happens to my `layout.ejs` file?

If you use the `/linker` folder, sails will alter your `layout.ejs` file to include links to your javascript and css files.  Therefore, any page served from the project's `/views` folder will have access to the javascript and css contained in these files.

Grunt uses commented tags in `layout.ejs` to as placehodler for these links.  For example, anything placed in the `/style` folder will automatically be linked in `layout.ejs` between these two tags:

```
<!--STYLES-->    
<!--STYLES END-->
```

Anything in the `/js` folder will be linked between these two tags:

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

Anyting in the `/templates` folder will be linked between these two tags:

```
<!--TEMPLATES-->   
<!--TEMPLATES END-->
```

#### Accessing Sail's Assets

Here's how you access the assets under either scenario:

**USING** the `/linker` folder

`/js` --> `/linker/js/yourFile.js`

`/styles` --> `/linker/styles/yourCSS.css`

**NOT USING** the `/linker` folder

`/js` --> `/js/yourFile.js`

`/styles` --> `/styles/yourCSS.css`

Comment: Thanks for your extensive help! In the end I just wrote my own small Gruntfile that minifies my JavaScripts and compiles my LESS files and copies them to the `.tmp` directory. That way the Gruntfile isn't as bloated as the default that comes with SailsJS. Still accepting your answer because it's a good description for anyone willing to follow Sails' system :)