# SailsJS can't access index.html located in assets/app

Tags: javascript, sails.js

Sails version: v0.12.11
Node version: v6.6.0
NPM version: v3.10.3
Operating system: Windows 10

Hello. I've just created a new sails app with sails new app --no-frontend. Now I need to import my reactjs app. I've created assets/app/index.html (following this http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets) and trying to access it via http://localhost:1337/app/index.html, but each time i've got a 404 error from a network tab. Should I manually add something in routes.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When app created with --no-frontend there is no grunt file and tasks. So none of my assets will be managed by sails. I've manually created .tmp/public/app folder and put my index.html there. Now it works. I've found solution here  [Manually include assets in SailsJS 0.9.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325810/manually-include-assets-in-sailsjs-0-9-7)

Comment: Accept your own answer to mark question as answered.